# If a sentence starts with a specific word, how to change a word in that sentence if it does exist?

Tags: perl, bash, awk

So, basically searching the lines in .txt file and if it starts with a word such as "This", how to swap a targeted word in that sentence if it does exist?  Open to doing it with bash, perl or awk.

Comment: do you want to change the word in the file?, or just cosole print

Comment: change the word in a file

Comment: @Exeter You're going to need to be a lot more specific. Did you say the *line* should begin with "This", or that the sentence would? Did you want to change the word "This", or some other word?

Comment: The first word in the line should begin with "This".  Then basically look for a target word in that line and be able to change the word in the document.  "sentence" was a bad word choice of mine.

Comment: An *example* is always a useful thing

Comment: Example:   "This can be."  (change can to can't) ->   "This can't be."

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -pi -e "s/^This\b/That/" myfile
```

or, if you want to change a *different* word within the line,

```
perl -pi -e "s/\btargeted\b/swap/ if /^This\b/" myfile
```

Comment: Looking close... just need to be able to find a word in the sentence that starts with "This" and then be able to change that word.

Comment: @Exeter: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that your requirements are different now? Are you distinguishing between a *line* and a *sentence*. Why are you talking about sentences again now that you have said the word is a bad choice?

Comment: I think it's a force of habit.  I tried the second solution but gets this:   String found where operator expected at perl5.pl line 1, near "pie "s/\bcan\b/can't/ if /^This\b/""
        (Do you need to predeclare pie?)
syntax error at perl5.pl line 1, near "pie "s/\bcan\b/can't/ if /^This\b/""
Execution of perl5.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Exeter Those are one-liners, not to be used inside a script. Unless its a shell/batch script.

Comment: When I put it directly into the shell, it says: Can't open perl script "s/\bcan\b/can't/ if /^This\b/": No such file or directory  (But the file does exist)

Comment: @Exeter Sounds like you forgot the `-e` switch there, partner. The `-e` switch means you don't use a program file, just the line of code following the switch itself, e.g. `perl -e 'print "Hi"'`.

Comment: Isn't that included in "-pie"?  Here's what ran in my shell: perl -pie "s/\bcan\b/can't/ if /^This\b/" file1.txt (which returned the following)
Can't open perl script "s/\bcan\b/can't/ if /^This\b/": No such file or directory

Comment: @Exeter: I'm sorry. It was taking the `e` as a parameter to the `i` switch. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Hey, that works good!  I guess I do have one requirements change.  How can I iterate over all files in a directory rather than a single file?

Comment: @Exeter: Just use a wildcard in the file name. use `*.txt` for all files with a `.txt` extension for instance.

Comment: That worked, thanks. any way to have that work inside of a .pl file?  similar to "find . -type f -exec" in bash. I didn't know perl was choosy whether it was single line as TLP mentioned above or in a file.