# If a line starts with a specific word, how to change a targeted word in that line if it does exist?

Tags: perl, bash

Looking to search through all files in a directory, looking at every line and if the line starts with a word such as "`This`", then search that line to find and replace a targeted word. I did get a solution for it being a one line command, but looking to have it as a perl file or a .txt file using bash if possible.

Example:

```
This rabbit jumped high

The rabbit jumped high
```

(find and replace high to low if the line starts with "This:

```
This rabbit jumped low

The rabbit jumped high
```

Comment: This seems trivial, please show what you've tried. It's just an `if` and `s///`.

Comment: You already asked the question here: “[If a sentence starts with a specific word, how to change a word in that sentence if it does exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371999/if-a-sentence-starts-with-a-specific-word-how-to-change-a-word-in-that-sentence)”. Putting the command into a script is kind of trivial

Comment: @Barmar, I haven't tried anything, I don't know how to do it if it's on a script, I have only seen a solution on how to do it at the command line which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371999/if-a-sentence-starts-with-a-specific-word-how-to-change-a-word-in-that-sentence

Comment: @amon, yes, that is what I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Do you know how to write an `if` statement in perl? Do you know how to do a substitution in perl? Do you know how to loop over input in perl? Put them together and you have the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^This/{s/high/low/g}' file
```

will do it for you:

```
kent$  echo "This rabbit jumped high

The rabbit jumped high"|sed '/^This/{s/high/low/g}'
This rabbit jumped low

The rabbit jumped high
```

If you want to replace **word** "high" instead of **text** high:

```
sed '/^This/{s/\<high\>/low/g}' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "This rabbit jumped high with highfoo      

The rabbit jumped high"|sed '/^This/{s/\<high\>/low/g}' 
This rabbit jumped low with highfoo

The rabbit jumped high
```

Comment: @fedorqui substitute all high with low.

Comment: Yes, I know the `s/high/low/g` syntax. The one I wasn't familiar to is the `/^This/{}`, I suppose it is a conditional in which case the `{}` is executed.

Comment: @fedorqui yes you are right. and the `{}` in this answer could be omitted. because if matched `/^This/` there is only one command `s`. `{}` would be useful if there are multi-commands need to be done when the line in a condition. similar as `if(foo){ }`

Comment: That's pretty cool, good to know. Thanks for the explanation, it is clear to me now :)

Comment: What I'm looking for is something that can read all documents in a directory and change the word in that file.

Comment: @Exeter you just replace the `file` with `*.txt` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your one line command in a bash script.

What was the one line command, what was wrong with it, and what is your difficulty with translating it?  It's kind of rude to have a solution and not share it with us while asking for us to duplicate the solution in a different way.

Comment: Sorry, here is the answer for that.  One poster said it couldn't be done in a script so I didn't include it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371999/if-a-sentence-starts-with-a-specific-word-how-to-change-a-word-in-that-sentence

Answer (score 1):

It would be very complicated to do this in `bash`, but the power of shells reside in their ability to call other programs (such as Perl) to do the heavy lifting.

If there can only be at most one targeted word per line:

```
perl -pe's/^This\b.*\K\bhigh\b/low/'
```

Otherwise,

```
perl -pe's/\bhigh\b/low/ if /^This\b/'
```

Notes:

- Only what's after the `\K` is replaced. ("K" for "keep").
- `\b` helps make sure "This" and "high" is not part of another word (like "thight").

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...'            # From STDIN to STDOUT
perl -pe'...' file       # From file(s) to STDOUT
perl -i~ -pe'...' file   # Edit file(s) "in-place" (with backup).
perl -i -pe'...' file    # Edit file(s) "in-place" (without backup).
```